# How to create a "go back" or "cancel" button on the node add form?

Tags: 8, forms

I'm trying to add a "cancel" button to my content type.

In `hook_form_alter()`, I'm using this code:

```
  if ($form_state->getFormObject()->getOperation() == 'default') { // On node add, make it clear "cancel" deletes any input
    // Do not show cancel button to people who have not completed their profile.
    if ($user->hasPermission('create MYTYPE content')) {
      $form['actions']['submit_cancel'] = array (
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#weight' => 999,
        '#value' => t('Delete all input and return to previous page'),
        '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_userpageredirect_callback'),
        );
      $form['actions']['submit_cancel']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'btn-danger';
    }
  }
```

....

```
/**
 * Cancel changes and return to previous page
 * @param array $form
 * @param FormStateInterface $form_state
 */
function MYMODULE_userpageredirect_callback(array &$form, FormStateInterface &$form_state) {
  $route_name = 'user.page';
  $form_state->setRedirect($route_name);
}
```

This creates a cancel button that returns the user to the user page when they click cancel.

**Problem**

If a field is marked required, and the user has not input any text in the field, the browser prompts the user to input a value into the field before the cancel button will work.

Comment: In this case you might need to override the validation function in your hook_form_alter.

Comment: Module [cancel_button](https://www.drupal.org/project/cancel_button) provides that functionality.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Adding `'#limit_validation_errors'` will help override validation,

```
$form['actions']['submit_cancel'] = array (
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#weight' => 999,
  '#value' => t('Delete all input and return to previous page'),
  '#submit' => array('MYMODULE_userpageredirect_callback'),
  '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
);
```

Comment: This one does the job. Thank you!